# Accessing an object class member without self.var in a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view outlet in my view controller. It's defined like this:

```
IBOutlet MyView * view;
```

The *MyView* class has some instance methods in it. I try to use them in the view controller like this:

```
int x = [view someMethod:4];
```

Xcode doesn't show any warning, no runtime errors are produced, but it doesn't call the method at all.
When I call the method like this:

```
int x = [self.view someMethod:4];
```

It suddenly works. Why is that? Why can't I access the *view* variable directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `view` may be non-initialized (i.e. `= nil`) when you call `[view someMethod:4]`, hence nothing happens.

However, calling `self.view` will guarantee `-loadView` be called, which in turn guarantee your `view` to be initialized, so it works.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear :)
Can I call loadView explicitly in the UIViewController constructor?

Comment: @Dor: You can, but you shouldn't.